# Is there a codegenerator for JAX-RS classes?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a set of entity classes. `Book` and `Student` for example. Now i want to write JAX-RS classes that offer CRUD operations like this.

```
    @Path("book")
    @Stateless
    public class BookREST{

      @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager em;

      @Path("save")
      @POST
      public void saveBook(Book b){
        em.persist(b);
      }

      @Path("delete")
      @DELETE
      public void deleteBook(Book b){
        em.remove(b);
      }
      //and so on
    }
```

and

```
    @Path("student")
    @Stateless
    public class StudentREST{

      @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager em;

      @Path("save")
      @POST
      public void saveStudent(Student s){
        em.persist(s);
      }

      @Path("delete")
      @DELETE
      public void deleteStudent(Student s){
        em.remove(s);
      }
      //and so on
    }
```

So in the end I have a couple of JAX-RS classes that are the same except for the `@Path` annotation like in this example `@Path("book")` and `@Path("student")`.

Is there a better way to write such classes? Or is there even a tool/maven plugin that I can pass my entity classes and which generates the JAX-RS classes for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NetBeans has such a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

İf you are asking that `webservices from entities` , you can create them automatically with Netbeans

```
New File > Webservice > Restful Webservices from entity classes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Eclipse, you could use the [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) Framework with [Texo](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Texo) and [Texo/JSON REST Web Services](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Texo/JSON_REST_Web_Services). This way you can create a entity model and generate entities from it. The Texo Web Services can be used to perform CRUD operations on entities.